# DataContractSerializer writes corrupted data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm using the following code to store some objects on disk:

```
    public static void Save<T>(T obj, string filename)
    {
        using (var output = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
        using (var writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(output, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        {
            Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
        })
        {
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
        }
    }
```

Sometimes the saved file gets corrupted, which means it consist of some random additional garbage data that prevents further deserialization, for example something like this:

```
<Parameters xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp">
    ...
</Parameters>eters>
```

Here last 6 characters come from some remains of the tag and prevent from deserializing this file. Why it happens and how can I fix it?

Can it be caused by calling the `Save` method in `Form.Closing` event handler?

Comment: Kinda looks like you're writing to the same file repeatedly, and the file isn't being truncated before you write it again. If what you wrote to it last time was six characters longer and ended with "`</Parameters>`" the same as the new one -- there you are. `System.IO.File.Delete(filename);` as the first line in the method should clear that up, I would think. Not sure if that throws when the file doesn't exist though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Of course! from documentation of OpenWrite: "Opens an existing file or creates a new file for writing." Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `new System.IO.FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)` instead of `OpenWrite`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov You had the proper answer first -- post it and I'll delete mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented behavior with `OpenWrite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The OpenWrite method opens a file if one already exists for the file path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. **If you overwrite a longer string** (such as “This is a test of the OpenWrite method”) **with a shorter string** (such as “Second run”), **the file will contain a mix of the strings** (“Second runtest of the OpenWrite method”).

So you need to explicitly truncate the file before writing, or just delete it if it exists.

Alexander Petrov observes that `new System.IO.FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)` is the correct replacement for `OpenWrite()` in this case.